# Is there a way to programmatically open the android call forwarding settings screen

Tags: android, android-intent

Is there any way to open the Android's existing Call Froward settings screen?

I'm pretty sure I can make one myself, but as always, it'll be better to reuse what is already in the phone. If I can.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
```

This opens the general phone settings, but I can't find the intent identifier to open the actual CF configuration screen.

Comment: I have same problem, seem impossible any success?

Comment: That seems to be the reality of it, sadly.

Comment: You can activate the call forwarding programatically